# ZF3 - Call a function with parameters in factories' Module class

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, servicemanager, zf3

I'm new in ZendFramework3 and I just want to know if it's possible to call a function with more arguments than just the serviceManager in factories (within my Module class) : (Is it possible to pass an argument next to the `$sm` argument?)

```
//class Module

//getConfig()
//getServiceConfig()

public function getControllerConfig()
{
    return [
        'factories' => [
            Controller\ModuleController::class => function ($sm) {
                return new ModuleController($sm);
            }
        ]
    ];
}
```

Comment: This is the SM from v2, Anyway you decide which is the next one... Can you paste your specific problem?

Comment: I don't have a specific problem. I'm just looking for a solution to make a generic code which could work with all modules in my project. The main goal is not to create a factories for all my modules (A factory for each ModuleTable, A factory for each ModuleTableGateway, ... I want to parameterize only one factory to work with every module I have. For doing that, I need to know which module is manipulated in my code. I can't use $this->getServiceLocator() anymore to get the right object (class) from my controller. Right, I just want to know if it is possible to get **function($sm, $another)**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create one "magical" factory for all dependencies, 
you should take a look at [SM AbstractFactory](https://zendframework.github.io/zend-servicemanager/configuring-the-service-manager/#abstract-factories).

In that one factory you can check from the **$requestedName** what will be dependencies. For eg. you can read dependencies from class constructor and than inject that dependencies (or pull it again from $container). You can also set your dependencies in config, and in that way create only one factory for all your classes.

Comment: yeah! That's what I need. Thank you so much. Just one thing, they do not specify where we have to create the ServiceManager. That's the point I don't understand. They just say "//When creating the service manager:" but where do we need to define it ?     // When creating the service manager: $serviceManager = new ServiceManager([
    'factories' => [
        MyObjectA::class => MyObjectFactory::class,
        MyObjectB::class => MyObjectFactory::class
    ]
]);

Comment: that is created by default if you are using framework.. check ZF skeleton https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication after instalation take a look in index.php file and around...

Comment: I am using the framework and I used ZendSkeleton. But I took a look in index.php file but It does not indicate me anything about the serviceManager. It will be a real pleasure if you could show me where it is :) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You may (for sure) pass other Arguments to Factory, so long as the Class to be created can handle the Arguments gracefully. In the example below, a Factory Class was created inside the Controller Directory. This is now the factory- ModuleControllerFactory - that instantiates the ModuleController.

```
<?php

    namespace Application\Controller;

    use Application\Controller\ModuleController,
        Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface,
        Zend\ServiceManager\Factory,
        Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;

    class ModuleControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface {

        public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options=null){
            // WE WANT TO PASS $variable1 to $variable12 TO THE ModuleController
            $variable1      = "Variable Value 1";
            $variable2      = "Variable Value 2";
            $variable3      = "Variable Value 3";
            return new ModuleController($container, $variable1, $variable2, $variable3);
        }
    }
```

So, now we can create the Constructor of the ModuleController Class:

```
  <?php

    // FILE-NAME: ModuleController.php;
    namespace Application\Controller;
    use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;

    class ModuleController extends AbstractActionController {
        /**
         * ContainerInterface.
         * @var ContainerInterface
         */
        public $container;

        /**
         * @var string
         */
        public $var1;

        /**
         * @var string
         */
        public $var2;

        /**
         * @var string
         */
        public $var3;

        //  CONTAINER & VARIALBLES INJECTED IN CONSTRUCTOR
        public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container, $variable1=null, $variable2=null, $variable3=null) {
            $this->container    = $container;
            $this->var1         = $variable1;
            $this->var2         = $variable2;
            $this->var3         = $variable3;
        }

        // JUST PLAY WITH THE INJECTED VALUES IN THE INDEX ACTION
        public function indexAction() {
            return new ViewModel([
                'container' => $this->container,
                'var1'      => $this->var1,
                'var2'      => $this->var2,
                'var3'      => $this->var3
            ]);
        }


    }
```

And now, update the `module.config.php` inside the config Folder of your module Example: `module/Application/config/module.config.php`.

```
<?php

    namespace Application;

    use Zend\Router\Http\Literal;
    use Zend\Router\Http\Regex;
    use Zend\Router\Http\Segment;
    use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory;

    return [
          //...
        'router' => [
          //...
        ],
        'controllers' => [
            'factories' => [
                Controller\ModuleController::class => Controller\ModuleControllerFactory::class
            ]
        ]
          //...

    ];
```